# how show image name in file type textbox in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am creating a simple crud application in which one is a admin part and other is a dashboard for user in which i also have a edit part but when i click on edit button all data show in text boxis but the image is not when it just show on type text box but not in type file please help me thank in advance..

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.imageURL, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.imageURL, new { htmlAttributes = new {Type="file"} })           
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Type="file"` is for generating a form control to select a file! And the property your binding to would need to be `HttpPostedFileBase` (which clearly its not). Its not clear what your asking, or what your trying to do.

Comment: i just want that when user click on edit link all values show in text boxes but the image show in file type input field. and all values are showing in text boxes but the image value is not how i can show it also?

Comment: values show in text boxes in sense of user edit them all values are showing in text boxes for example name=adil password=*** bla bla bla but tha <input type=file/> this filed not get the image name value m very worried about please solve this.

Comment: in think it is jiust a sentex problam u can check my code above and somve this it is just a razer view problam

Comment: You cannot set the value of a file input for security reasons! The only way it can be set is by the user selecting a file in their browser.

Comment: so what i do as its alternate when user click edit link but suddenly he/she remind that all values are correct and no need to change anything but in this case it will become necessary for him/her to change its image otherwise it save a null instead of image name in database please guide me...